# wav sound is different on a public drive

Tags: windows, vba, excel, wav

I have a macro that plays a wav file.  The sound is a "click" and it is played 5 times in a loop.  Below is the line of code that is used to play the wav file:

```
sndPlaySound32 "C:\Temp\Click2.wav", SND_SYNC

sndPlaySound32 "W:\Users\Game\Click2.wav", SND_SYNC
```

When the wav file is stored on my hard drive, it sounds like the "click" I expect to hear.  When it is stored on the public "W" drive, it is a Windows "ding".

Why does the file sound differently when it is on a different drive?  Is there setting I can change to avoid the Windows "ding".

Thanks for the help.....

Comment: you double checked that the W: file really is what you think it is?

Comment: @MarcB.......Thanks for the suggestion.  I went back and checked and found I didn't actually have the wav file in the folderl.  Once I put it in the folder, it worked like I expected it to.  Thanks for the help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your filename and filepath, my guess is that the file wasn't found and you're hearing the default.  From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798676(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If the specified sound cannot be found, sndPlaySound plays the system
>   default sound. If there is no system default entry in the registry or
>   WIN.INI file, or if the default sound cannot be found, the function
>   makes no sound and returns FALSE.

If you want to disable this behavior, pass the `SND_NODEFAULT` flag:

```
sndPlaySound32 "C:\Temp\Click2.wav", (SND_SYNC Or SND_NODEFAULT)
```

Comment: @Comintern......you were correct.  the file was found because it wasn't there.  Once I put the wav file, it worked like I expected it to.  I had everything else that I needed in the folder except for the wav file.  Thanks for the suggestion.....